# Retrieve IMDB poster picture with php/js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, url

Is there a way I can retrieve the IMDB main poster image for a certain film, if I just have the url to the film page? (imdb.com)

Using php, perhaps js/jquery

Comment: PHP and scrape the page using a framework. Don't use regexp.

Comment: Yes there is. If you are happy with a smaller version, the image on the page always has the ID="primary-poster"

Comment: Small/simple is good. It's not for something fancy. Could you help me to how I would do it more excactly? ;)

Comment: Perhaps this is what I need, but it uses title instead of url https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/grab-movie-poster-from-imdb.2639242/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can retreive IMDB movie posters.Firstly, You must connect IMDB website by the curl or php's file_get_contents(); function.Also, you should parse HTML and you should find a regular expression and you must get the link of image.I explained simple of code in the following segment:

```
<?php 
    $URL = "There will be movie detail page";
    $DetailPage = file_get_content($URL);
    $ImageSource = preg_match("/ regex will be here /i",$DetailPage,$ImageSource); //Here you must find a image from source.
    $Image_Tag = $ImageSource[0]; // it's a image tag from IMDB you should get inside of src=""
    ...
    ...
    $ImageLink = ...
    $PosterImage = file_get_contents($ImageLink);
    file_put_contents("your_image_folder/your_posters_name.jpg", $PosterImage);

?>
```

**UPDATED:**
I would not information about, there is a IMDB API and it's simple and easy to getting image url from API.You have to parse json if you have to use API.There is a simple code for getting image from IMDB by API in the following segment of code:

```
<?php 
$URL = "http://www.imdbapi.com/?i=&t=inception";
$Page = file_get_contents($URL);
$MovieInformations = json_decode($Page);
$Poster = $MovieInformations["Poster"];

$GetImage = file_get_contents($Poster);
file_put_contents("your_image_folder/your_posters_name.jpg", $GetImage);
?>
```

Comment: Looks promising. But I'm totally out of practice with regex.. could you help set it up? ;)

Comment: Yep.I could but there is more easy way in the link which is you shared on comment.

Comment: I shared new code about them.I think it's more easer than first one for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php scripting to get the data from another site follow the method below

1) Add file 'simple_html_dom.php' available on internet

set_time_limit(o);
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

2) Define the function  scraping_IMDB and saveImg  :

```
function scraping_IMDB($url) 
{
    $html = file_get_html($url);

    $ret['path'] = '';
     foreach($html->find('div[class="post"] img[class="wp-post-image"]') as $e)
     {
      $ret['path'] = $e->src;
     }

    $html->clear();
    unset($html);

    return $ret;
}

function saveImg($url) 
{
  $i = file_get_contents($url);
  $name = end(explode('/',rtrim($url,'/')));
  $f = fopen('photos/'.$name,'w+');
  fwrite($f,$i);
  fclose($f);
}
```

3) call the finction with the url:

```
$ret = scraping_IMDB('http://imdb.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for inputs.
I found, the easiest and simplest way for me is to use this:

```
function getImage($imdbid)
{
  $source = file_get_contents('http://www.imdbapi.com/?i='.$imdbid);
  $decode = json_decode($source, true);
  return $decode['Poster'];
}
```

First, extract the movie id from the url, and then use getImage($theidfromtheurl).
Voila