# How to strip a string from unwanted parts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, imdb

Given an url like this:

```
https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTM3MTc3OTc0NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTQ0OTM1MQ@@._V1._CR34,0,295,440_UX32_CR0,0,32,44_AL_.jpg
```

How do i get it to be like

```
https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTM3MTc3OTc0NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTQ0OTM1MQ@@._V1._CR34,44_AL_.jpg
```

The issue I am having is with retrieving IMDB poster images, using this:

```
$('form[name="search-imdb"]').on("submit", function(e) {
  var form = $(this);
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
     url: "http://imdb.wemakesites.net/api/search",
     data: form.serialize(), // assuming the form has a hidden input with api_key name, containing your API key
     crossDomain: true,
     dataType: "jsonp",
     success: function(data) {
       window.console.log(data);
     }
  });
});
```

I get a json response like:

```
"thumbnail": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTYwOTEwNjAzMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODc5MTUwMw@@._V1_UX32_CR0,0,32,44_AL_.jpg"
```

I get no poster and [the api i am using](http://imdb.wemakesites.net/#anhcor-api-endpoint) don't help, yet that thumbnail image is including various formats, one of which is `44_al` which is what i would like to leave as a string in order to output it like:

```
function imdbLoad() {
  var form = $("#usp-title").val();
  var encodedTerm = encodeURIComponent(form);
        $.ajax({
           url: "http://imdb.wemakesites.net/api/search",
           data: {
             q: encodedTerm
           },
           crossDomain: true,
           dataType: "jsonp",
           success: function(data) {
             $("#imdb").empty();
             $.each(data.data.results, function(i, items) {
               $("#imdb").append('<h2>'+i+'</h2>');
               $.each(items, function(k, item) {
                 $("#imdb").append("<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4'><div class='thumbnail'><img class='img-responsive' src='"+ item.thumbnail +"'><div class='caption'><h3>"+ item.title +"</h3><p>"+ item.title +"</p></div></div>");
               });
             });
           }
        });
}
```

Unless anyone has any other way to grab the poster url

Comment: This answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057626/retrieve-imdb-poster-picture-with-php-js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057626/retrieve-imdb-poster-picture-with-php-js) might be helpful for you.

Comment: @vijaymishra thanks, didn't see it, looks promising, Will try it now

Comment: @vijaymishra the json isn't providing Poster as that answer suggest with $decode['Poster'];

Comment: If all of the url's have the same pattern, you could simply use a split string on the ',' and then just select the parts you need =]

Comment: Check if it works for you http://99webtools.com/blog/php-get-movie-information-from-imdb/. Please acknowledge if it works. It is mentioned there that imdbapi is not working anymore.

Comment: @vijaymishra thanks, that's php tho. The jquery api works, we just don't get "poster", the only solution i can think of is with split string as we do get the img url both by id search and plain search http://imdb.wemakesites.net/

Comment: @krisph yeah that's the way to go, only way i could find and think of too, that's what the question is asking in fact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use regex to replace string part that is not required

```js
var url = "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTM3MTc3OTc0NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTQ0OTM1MQ@@._V1._CR34,0,295,440_UX32_CR0,0,32,44_AL_.jpg"
var regex = /,.*(?=,)/g;
console.log(url.replace(regex, ''))
```

or split using comma(`,`) and join first and last part.

```js
var url = "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTM3MTc3OTc0NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTQ0OTM1MQ@@._V1._CR34,0,295,440_UX32_CR0,0,32,44_AL_.jpg"

var parts = url.split(',');
console.log(parts[0] + ',' + parts.pop())
```

Comment: i will accept it as i forgot to include my own answer but yes, split string is the way to go. Also had to do another filtering check with the url as some movies aren't with an image but in the url will have the string "nopicture" which i could check and skipt as a result

Comment: In that case, do not accept this as an answer. Post your answer and explain it so that someone in future gets better picture. Once you post your answer, I'll delete my answer

Comment: ok done, pasted my own answer but keep yours as it answered the question and i leave it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a longer code as I have included few bits such as limiting the number of results but basically what I noticed is that after the @@ the whole string is about image size. So instead of using a regex (that would be the answer for this specific question), I could simply add the dimension to the url as a string like:

```
<img class='img-responsive' src='"+ thumbnailMod[0] + "@._V1_UX500_CR0,0,500,550_AL_.jpg'>
```

Full code

```
$('form[name="search-imdb"]').on("submit", function(e) {
  var form = $(this);
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://imdb.wemakesites.net/api/search",
    data: {
      api_key: "...",
      q: form.find('input[name="q"]').val()
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#imdb").empty();
      var thumbnailMod, limiteRes = 1;
      if (data.data.results.titles !== undefined) {
        $("#imdb").append('<h2>Titles</h2>');
        $.each(data.data.results.titles, function(i, item) {
          thumbnailMod = item.thumbnail.split('@.');
          if (thumbnailMod.length > 1) {
            if (limiteRes > 3) {
                return;
            }
            limiteRes++;
            $("#imdb").append("<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4'><div class='thumbnail'><img class='img-responsive' src='"+ thumbnailMod[0] + "@._V1_UX500_CR0,0,500,550_AL_.jpg'><div class='caption'><h3>"+ item.title +"</h3><p>"+ item.title +"</p></div></div>");
          }
        });

      } else {
        console.log('No titles found for this search.');
      }
    }
  });
});
```